# FortiGate 100E IPSec disconnect

Tags: ipsec, fortigate

I think this problem is well known that the FortiGate does not reconnect IPSec tunnels sometimes.

Is there a way to keep the tunnel open. Do I have to buy a newer product or update to a newer OS?

Answer (score 0):

Are both IPSec tunnels connected with Fortigate ?
It's more an IPsec configuration issue than the Fortigate itself.

Please check **idle-timeout** in order to maintain a connection.